# Which property of a triangle ABC can show that if $\sin A = \cos B\times \tan C$, then $CF, BE, AD$ are concurrent?

Tags: geometry, triangles

Qn: Prove that in a triangle ABC [image: here] the altitude through C, the median through B
and the internal angle bisector through A are concurrent iff $sin C = cos B\times tan A$.

Attempt1: By cevas theorem we can say that $\frac{CE}{AE}\times \frac{AF}{FB}\times \frac{CD}{DB} = 1$ . Going backwards from given equation, I get $ \ \ \ tanA = \frac{sinC}{cosB}$. Then by using right triangles I obtain $\ tanA = \frac{CF}{FA} \ \ , \ \ cosB= \frac{BF}{CB}$. $\\ \  $ Using this information how can I prove equation above to hold if and only if lines are concurrent?

Comment: This may be useful:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva%27s_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will calculate the following expresion:
$$\frac{\sin {\angle{EBA}}}{\sin {\angle{EBC}}}\cdot \frac{\sin {\angle{DAC}}}{\sin {\angle{FCA}}}\cdot\frac{\sin {\angle{FCB}}}{\sin {\angle{DAB}}}$$
Since $\angle{DAB}=\angle{DAC}$ expression becomes
$$\frac{\sin {\angle{EBA}}}{\sin {\angle{EBC}}}\cdot\frac{\sin {\angle{FCB}}}{\sin {\angle{FCA}}}$$
Now $\angle{FCA}=90-A,\angle{FCB}=90-B$
Another hand if we use Sin Law for triangles $BEA$ and $ECB$ we get that
$$\frac{EA}{\sin \angle{EBA}}=\frac{BE}{\sin \angle{A}},\quad \frac{BE}{\sin \angle{C}}=\frac{CE}{\sin \angle{EBC}}$$
If we multiply those two and since $EC=EA$ we get that
$$\frac{\sin \angle{EBA}}{\sin \angle{EBC}}=\frac{\sin \angle{A}}{\sin \angle{C}}$$
So combine those two equations we get that 
$$\frac{\sin {\angle{EBA}}}{\sin {\angle{EBC}}}\cdot\frac{\sin {\angle{FCB}}}{\sin {\angle{FCA}}}=\frac{\sin \angle{A}}{\sin \angle{C}}\cdot \frac{\sin \angle{90-B}}{\sin \angle{90-A}}=\frac{\sin \angle{A}}{\sin \angle{C}}\cdot \frac{\cos \angle{B}}{\cos \angle{A}}=\frac{\tan \angle{A}\cdot \cos \angle{b}}{\sin \angle{C}}$$
So from Ceva's theorem about trigometry we get that the altitude through C, the median through B and the internal angle bisector through A are concurrent if
$$\frac{\sin {\angle{EBA}}}{\sin {\angle{EBC}}}\cdot \frac{\sin {\angle{DAC}}}{\sin {\angle{FCA}}}\cdot\frac{\sin {\angle{FCB}}}{\sin {\angle{DAB}}}=1$$
So from our calculating
$$\frac{\sin {\angle{EBA}}}{\sin {\angle{EBC}}}\cdot \frac{\sin {\angle{DAC}}}{\sin {\angle{FCA}}}\cdot\frac{\sin {\angle{FCB}}}{\sin {\angle{DAB}}}=1$$
iff $\tan \angle{A}\cdot \cos \angle{b}=\sin \angle{C}$

Comment: I see this version of Cevian formula for the first time. Could you suggest source which shows derivation?

Comment: @AzatDjanybekov http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/TrigCeva.shtml